# USB Wireless Adapter recognized by `lsusb` but not by `ifconfig` on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, usb, kali-linux

I am experiencing some issues with an Wireless Adapter. Long story short:

- I have a USB Wireless Adapter: `AWUS036ACH` (chipset: `RTL8812AU`)
- drivers are up to date: (i.e., `apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms`)
- the card is recognized by `lsusb` (i.e., both in VirtualBox and USB live boot)
- the card is not listed by `ifconfig -a`

Here is the output of some of the commands I tried:

- `uname -r`:

  ```
  4.14.0-kali1-amd64
  ```
- `lsusb`:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
  Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
  Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
  ```
- `ifconfig -a`:

  ```
  eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
  # more details removed
  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
  # more details removed
  ```
- `apt-get install realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms`:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  realtek-rtl88xxau-dkms is already the newest version (5.1.5~20171206-0kali1).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  ```

Additional information:

- the network adapter in VirtualBox is set to `NAT`, however this may not be relevant because the same issue occurs when I do a live boot
- the cards works on Windows and [it is supported by Kali too](https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-20171-release/)
- just to make sure, I also tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Do you have any ideas what I am missing? Thank you.

---

**Edit:**

- I installed the driver using the `dkms` as described in the [aircrack-ng](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au) repository and it worked. **Note:** If you run the installation in VirtualBox, the `USB` controller must be set to `xHCI` (3.0).
- @sawdust suggested the following [link on Kali forums](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?36814-How-to-install-AWUS036ACH-Drivers-and-getting-it-running) which may be very helpful.

Comment: Inspect the system log (i.e.`dmesg`) for your adapter requesting a firmware load, and whether it was successful.

Comment: @sawdust I followed your suggestion and, first I cleaned the `var/log/messages` file and, then, I rebooted the system. Couldn't find anything. I searched for these keywords: `realtek`, `8812`, `firmware`, `wifi`. This is the only thing that caught my eye: `manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file`. Any clue what should I try next?

Comment: @sawdust No clue if this is relevant, but I also see the following: `gsd-rfkill[1296]: Error setting up rfkill: Could not open RFKILL control device, please verify your installation`.

The device appears to be loaded: `New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8812 | New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 | Product: 802.11n NIC | Manufacturer: Realtek`.

Comment: Have you tried kcdtv's suggestions at https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?36814-How-to-install-AWUS036ACH-Drivers-and-getting-it-running

Comment: I didn't see that post before. Thank you, I bookmarked it and I will edit the question to include the link. However, I just tried installing the driver from this repository (https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au) and it worked... I wish I knew why...

Comment: Kali is a distribution aimed at professional penetration testers, so many things that are easy in other distributions are [hard in Kali](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). People complain about not being able to use drivers for specific hardware all the time. I suggest changing the distribution; hardware will just work, or installing drivers will be much easier.